# How to mimic browser with ffmpeg for HLS stream?

Tags: ffmpeg

Command `ffmpeg -i http://keshethdioslive-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/221630/CH2LIVE_HIGH/index_2064.m3u8 -c strim.ts` not working. Probably it require cookies attached and I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

First, view the cookies in your browser and find all of the important ones for `akamaihd.net`. Then, use the `-cookies` option with ffmpeg. The syntax of that option is described [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#HTTP-Cookies).